# Add messages from server in apollo response (Nodejs)

Tags: apollo-server, vue-apollo, vaticle-typeql

When u api restful i will send response like :

```
{
data,
code: 1,
msg: 'This is the messages'
}
```

With response like that i can show a success message if code = 1, or error messages if code = 2,many thing.
But when i try use graphql (apollo response)...i dont know how to do that...response from apollo response just only have data i defined in Schema like this...i cant add anything else

```
{
  "data": {
    "getBanners": [
      {
        "link": "example.com",
        "avatar": null
      },
      {
        "link": "example.com",
        "avatar": "example.com/0_banner_1597917871_3211.jpg"
      },
      {
        "link": "example.com/16709365405930105",
        "avatar": "example.com/0_banner_1597917938_5116.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want response like when i use restful. How to do that. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could define a return type in your GraphQL schema:

```
type GetBannersResponse {
  data: [Banners]
  code: Int!
  msg: String
}
```

And then define this as the result when executing the query:

```
type Query{
  getBanners: GetBannersResponse
}
```

Now you should be able to request all objects you want and in the resolver of the query you can create an object containing your data.